# Which CFF font fields make a visual difference?

Tags: pdf, compact-font-format

I'm writing a converter for CFF (PostScript Type 2) fonts, and I'm wondering which fields the converter can remove without making any visual difference when the font is used in a PDF file.

I think these fields can be removed or changed:

- `/FontName`
- `/PostScript.FSType`
- `/PostScript.OrigFontType`
- `/PostScript.OrigFontName`
- `/PostScript.OrigFontStyle`
- `/FontInfo.version`
- `/FontInfo.Notice`
- `/FontInfo.Copyright`
- `/FontInfo.FullName`
- `/FontInfo.FamilyName`
- `/FontInfo.Weight`
- `/FontInfo.isFixedPitch`
- `/UniqueID`
- `/XUID`

I think these fields must be kept, because they affect the rendering:

- `/StrokeWidth`
- `/PaintType`
- `/CharstringType`
- `/FontMatrix`
- `/Encoding`
- `/CharStrings`
- `/Private.BlueValues`
- `/Private.OtherBlues`
- `/Private.FamilyBlues`
- `/Private.FamilyOtherBlues`
- `/Private.BlueScale`
- `/Private.BlueShift`
- `/Private.BlueFuzz`
- `/Private.StdHW`
- `/Private.StdVW`
- `/Private.StemSnapH`
- `/Private.StemSnapV`
- `/Private.Subrs`
- `/Private.GlobalSubrs`
- `/Private.defaultWidthX`
- `/Private.nominalWidthX`

I'm not sure about these fields:

- `/FontInfo.ItalicAngle`
- `/FontInfo.UnderlinePosition`
- `/FontInfo.UnderlineThickness`
- `/FontBBox`
- `/BaseFontName`
- `/BaseFontBlend`
- `/Private.ForceBold`
- `/Private.LanguageGroup`
- `/Private.ExpansionFactor`
- `/Private.initialRandomSeed`
- `/Private.unknown12015`

So, which of the fields above do and which of them don't make a visual difference in rendering, when the font is used in a PDF file?

Comment: If you remove notice and copyright you are probably breaking the law

Comment: Why would you want to throw away everything that doesn't make a visual difference in rendering? There are legal (as Kevin pointed out) and interoperational (your approach may hinder faithful text extraction) issues in doing so...

Comment: @mkl: The goal is to make the PDF output as small as possible, without any difference in visual rendering. I understand that this is not always a desirable goal (for legal and interoperability reasons), thus it's useful to know which CFF fields are useful for what reason, and it's worth asking follow-up questions. To make the question simple(r) to answer, I focused it on rendering only.